# Sed: delete lines without pattern except first

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

How to delete lines that do not match the pattern except the first line?

To delete lines except first i use
`sed '1!d'`

To delete lines that do not match patter i use
`sed '/pattern/!d'`

How can i use both of conditions? Things like
`sed '1!/pattern/!d'`
doesn't work, says unknown command: '/'

As example (if pattern="rcu")
from input

```
  PID  PPID PRI  NI    VSZ   RSS STAT     TIME CMD
    1     0  19   0  33664  4832 Ss   00:00:07 /sbin/init splash
    2     0  19   0      0     0 S    00:00:00 [kthreadd]
    3     2  39 -20      0     0 I<   00:00:00 [rcu_gp]
    4     2  39 -20      0     0 I<   00:00:00 [rcu_par_gp]
    8     2  39 -20      0     0 I<   00:00:00 [mm_percpu_wq]
    9     2  19   0      0     0 S    00:00:04 [ksoftirqd/0]
```

get

```
  PID  PPID PRI  NI    VSZ   RSS STAT     TIME CMD
    3     2  39 -20      0     0 I<   00:00:00 [rcu_gp]
    4     2  39 -20      0     0 I<   00:00:00 [rcu_par_gp]
```

Thanks

Comment: When you say `except the first` do you mean `except the first line of the input even if it doesn't match the regexp` or `except the first line that doesn't match the regexp` or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Output first line and all lines which contain `rcu`:

```
sed -n '1p; /rcu/p' file
```

Comment: Yeah it's most simple solution, thanks. Tried to do it in one command, my mistake

Comment: What if `rcu` is in the first line? perhaps `sed '1b;/rcu/!d' file`?

Comment: Much better than my work-around `grep -E 'PID|rcu'`.

Comment: @potong: or search only from second line (`2`) to last (`$`): `sed -n '1p; 2,${/rcu/p}' file`

Answer (score 0):

You could also make a script that reads the file and “extracts” first line that don’t match the pattern (to another temporary file or to the string), make other operations like deleting lines that you want to be deleted and paste that line back in the same place in the file.

Comment: That should be a comment rather than an answer but that wouldn't be a good approach anyway, the solution is much simpler than that.

Answer (score 0):

As you have tagged `awk`

```
awk '{if ($0~/rcu/) print}'
```

Demo :

```
$ cat file1.txt
  PID  PPID PRI  NI    VSZ   RSS STAT     TIME CMD
    1     0  19   0  33664  4832 Ss   00:00:07 /sbin/init splash
    2     0  19   0      0     0 S    00:00:00 [kthreadd]
    3     2  39 -20      0     0 I<   00:00:00 [rcu_gp]
    4     2  39 -20      0     0 I<   00:00:00 [rcu_par_gp]
    8     2  39 -20      0     0 I<   00:00:00 [mm_percpu_wq]
    9     2  19   0      0     0 S    00:00:04 [ksoftirqd/0]
$ awk '{if ($0~/rcu/) print}' file1.txt
    3     2  39 -20      0     0 I<   00:00:00 [rcu_gp]
    4     2  39 -20      0     0 I<   00:00:00 [rcu_par_gp]
$
```

Comment: `awk '{if ($0~/rcu/) print}'` is equivalent to just `awk '/rcu/'`. It doesn't address the "except the first" aspect of the question though.

Answer (score 0):

If when you say `except the first` if you mean `except the first line of the input even if it doesn't match the regexp` then this is what you want:

```
$ awk '/rcu/ || NR==1' file
  PID  PPID PRI  NI    VSZ   RSS STAT     TIME CMD
    3     2  39 -20      0     0 I<   00:00:00 [rcu_gp]
    4     2  39 -20      0     0 I<   00:00:00 [rcu_par_gp]
```

or if you mean `except the first line that doesn't match the regexp` then this is what you want:

```
$ awk '/rcu/ || !c++' file
  PID  PPID PRI  NI    VSZ   RSS STAT     TIME CMD
    3     2  39 -20      0     0 I<   00:00:00 [rcu_gp]
    4     2  39 -20      0     0 I<   00:00:00 [rcu_par_gp]
```